# Efficiently Filtering out Sorted Data With A Second Predicate

Tags: algorithm, sorting, filter

Lets say that I have a list (or a hashmap etc., whatever makes this the fastest) of objects that contain the following fields: name, time added, and time removed.  The list given to me is already sorted by time removed.  Now, given a time T, I want to filter (remove from the list) out all objects of the list where:
the time T is greater than an object's time removed OR T is less than an object's time added.
So after processing, the list should only contain objects where T falls in the range specified by time added and time removed.

I know I can do this easily in O(n) time by going through each individual object, but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way considering the list was already sorted by the first predicate (time removed).

*Also, I know I can easily remove all objects with time removed less than T because the list is presorted (possibly in O(log n) time since I do a binary search to find the first element that is less than and then remove the first part of the list up to that object).

(Irrelevant additional info: I will be using C++ for any code that I write)

Comment: `Also, I know I can easily remove all objects with time removed less than T because the list is presorted (possibly in O(log n) time since I do a binary search to find the first element that is less than and then remove the first part of the list up to that object).` No. Assume you have a list of `n` elements, and you want to filter out `n/2` of these. You can either remove the n/2 "unwanted" elements from it, in `O(n)`, or create a new list with the desired n/2 elements in O(n).

Comment: You can use lazy evaluation if you only want to iterate - but it will just be moving the work from the `filter()` method to the `iterate()` method, no real gain there. However, in some implementations of trees (such as B+ trees), range queries can be quite efficient - but not in naive implementations of list (which are usually linked list or dynamic array).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you are stuck with a O(n) being your fastest option. **That is unless their are hidden requirements about the difference between time added and time removed (such as a max time span) that can be exploited.**

As you said you can start the search where the time removed equals (or is the first greater than) the time removed. Unfortunately you'll need to go through the rest of the list to see if time added is less than your time.

Because a comparative sort is at best O(n*log(n)) you cannot sort the objects again to improve your performance.

One thing, based on the heuristics of the application it may be beneficial to receive the data in order of date added but that is between you and wherever you get the data from.

Answer (score 1):

Let's examine the data structures you offered:

A list (usually implemented as a [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list), or a [dynamic array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array)), or a [hash map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

1. Linked List: Cannot do binary search, finding first occurance of an
   element (even if list is sorted) is done in `O(n)`, so no benefit
   from the fact the data is sorted.
2. Dynamic Array: Removing a single element (or more) from arbitrary location requires shifting all the following elements to the left, and thus is O(n). You cannot remove elements from the list better than `O(n)`, so no gain here from the fact the DS is sorted.
3. HashMap: is unsorted by definition. Also, removing `k` elements is `O(k)`, no way to go around this.

So, you cannot even improve performance from `O(n)` to `O(logn)` for the same field the list was sorted by.

---

Some data structures such as [B+ trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B+_tree) do allow efficient range queries, and you can pretty efficiently [`O(logn)`] remove a range of elements from the tree.

However, it does not help you to filter the data of the 2nd field, which the tree is unsorted by, and to filter according to it (unless there is some correlation you can exploit) - will still need `O(n)` time.

---

If all you are going to do is to later on iterate the new list, you can push the evaluation to the iteration step, but there won't be any real benefit from it - only delaying the processing to when it's needed, and avoiding it, if it is not needed.